# Copy struct with nested maps

Tags: pointers, go, reference

**What am I trying to do?**

Copy a "default" struct into a new one when needed, keeping all it's values.

**Details**

I am trying to copy a `Chat` struct:

```
type ChatData struct {
        User map[string]map[string]string `json:"user"`
        Chat map[string]string            `json:"chat"`
}
type Chat struct {
        Settings map[string]map[string]interface{} `json:"settings"`
        Data     ChatData                          `json:"data"`
}
```

I only need to do this when a new chat is introduced, and I check for membership in a `map[string]Chat`.

```
//data is a map[string]Chat
if _, exists := data[event.Chat]; !exists {
        data[event.Chat] = data["default"]
}
```

The full default struct is:

```
{
    "default": {
        "settings": {
            "eightball": {
                "messages": [
                    "yes",
                    "no",
                    "maybe"
                ]   
            },  
            "main": {
                "blacklistedCommands": [], 
                "blacklistedUsers": [], 
                "error": "there was an error - ",
                "maxConsecutive": 5,
                "permissions": "You don't have permissions for that command.",
                "success": "The command was successful.",
                "whitelistedCommands": [], 
                "whitelistedUsers": []
            }   
        },  
        "data": {
            "user": {
                "default": {
                    "admin": "false",
                    "consecutiveCommands": "0",
                    "nickname": "", 
                    "sentMessages": "0" 
                },  
                "total": {
                    "admin": "false",
                    "consecutiveCommands": "0",
                    "nickname": "", 
                    "sentMessages": "0" 
                }   
            },  
            "chat": {
                "commandSender": "", 
                "lastMessage": "", 
                "lastSender": "", 
                "lastTimestamp": "", 
                "wasCommand":""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What have I tried**

```
data[event.Chat] = data["default"]
// causes a reference

data[event.Chat] = &data["default"]
// cannot use &data["default"] (type *Chat) as type Chat in assignment

data[event.Chat] = *data["default"]
// invalid indirect of data["default"] (type Chat)
```

Do I need to change my use of `map[string]Chat` to `map[string]*Chat` and go with the second option? Pointers and references are not my specialty, so help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

whoever thought I was copying a map, what are you smoking?

Answer (score 3):

I have found in previous cases, that an easy (though not the most efficient) way to copy a complex structure is to Marshal it, and then Unmarshal it into a new variable.  This can be done with a variety of encodings.  Two easy ones (included in the stdlib) would be json and gob.

There are also plenty of libraries using reflection to achieve a similar goal: https://github.com/jinzhu/copier

But like I said, though not as efficient, this is easy to reason about and takes just a single, simple function to achieve.  If performance matters you should prefer gob over json.  If performance REALLY matters, then you should prefer another solution altogether.

Comment: do you know if changing `Chat to *Chat` would work?

Comment: Do note that this only works if all fields are exported though.

Comment: Good point @peter

Answer (score 1):

If you know the data structure it is best for you to fully define your structs. It will be much easier to manage than complex maps and interfaces with reflection to cast data types. Here is a tool to help you convert JSON to Go structs. It isn't perfect and you have to confirm the data types. You may even want to rip out the internal structs and create types for them for readability and maintenance, but it will save you some time.

https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var rawDataExample = []byte(`{
    "default": {
        "settings": {
            "eightball": {
                "messages": [
                    "yes",
                    "no",
                    "maybe"
                ]   
            },  
            "main": {
                "blacklistedCommands": [], 
                "blacklistedUsers": [], 
                "error": "there was an error - ",
                "maxConsecutive": 5,
                "permissions": "You don't have permissions for that command.",
                "success": "The command was successful.",
                "whitelistedCommands": [], 
                "whitelistedUsers": []
            }   
        },  
        "data": {
            "user": {
                "default": {
                    "admin": "false",
                    "consecutiveCommands": "0",
                    "nickname": "", 
                    "sentMessages": "0" 
                },  
                "total": {
                    "admin": "false",
                    "consecutiveCommands": "0",
                    "nickname": "", 
                    "sentMessages": "0" 
                }   
            },  
            "chat": {
                "commandSender": "", 
                "lastMessage": "", 
                "lastSender": "", 
                "lastTimestamp": "", 
                "wasCommand":""
            }
        }
    }
}
`)

type Settings struct {
    Default struct {
        Settings struct {
            Eightball struct {
                Messages []string `json:"messages"`
            } `json:"eightball"`
            Main struct {
                BlacklistedCommands []string `json:"blacklistedCommands"`
                BlacklistedUsers    []string `json:"blacklistedUsers"`
                Error               string   `json:"error"`
                MaxConsecutive      int      `json:"maxConsecutive"`
                Permissions         string   `json:"permissions"`
                Success             string   `json:"success"`
                WhitelistedCommands []string `json:"whitelistedCommands"`
                WhitelistedUsers    []string `json:"whitelistedUsers"`
            } `json:"main"`
        } `json:"settings"`
        Data struct {
            User struct {
                Default struct {
                    Admin               string `json:"admin"`
                    ConsecutiveCommands string `json:"consecutiveCommands"`
                    Nickname            string `json:"nickname"`
                    SentMessages        string `json:"sentMessages"`
                } `json:"default"`
                Total struct {
                    Admin               string `json:"admin"`
                    ConsecutiveCommands string `json:"consecutiveCommands"`
                    Nickname            string `json:"nickname"`
                    SentMessages        string `json:"sentMessages"`
                } `json:"total"`
            } `json:"user"`
            Chat struct {
                CommandSender string `json:"commandSender"`
                LastMessage   string `json:"lastMessage"`
                LastSender    string `json:"lastSender"`
                LastTimestamp string `json:"lastTimestamp"`
                WasCommand    string `json:"wasCommand"`
            } `json:"chat"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"default"`
}

type Data struct {
    Events map[string]Settings
}

func main() {
    var settings Settings
    err := json.Unmarshal(rawDataExample, &settings)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    event := "foo"
    d := Data{
        Events: make(map[string]Settings),
    }

    if _, ok := d.Events[event]; !ok {
        // event doesn't exist
        // add it
        d.Events[event] = settings
        fmt.Println("event added")
    }

    if _, ok := d.Events[event]; !ok {
        // event exist, this will never be happen
        // sanity check
        fmt.Println("this will never be printed")
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", d)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @reticentroot. I am creating a framework where I can add and remove data values as I need, for example adding an easter egg to the eightball. Having concrete types is nice, but I prefer the ease of development. Also having type switches and the easy `.(string)` keeps me doing it like this.

Comment: You could modify the struct above to use pointers `*string`, then when you delete an item you can set it to `nil`. If you add the omitempty flag to json tags, if marshaled to bytes, the field will no longer be present. Food for thought

Comment: @PLZHELP, concrete types are *much* easier to work with than untyped maps. The compiler will stop you long before bad things happen, for instance. And you must be getting tired of type assertions by now.

Comment: @Peter you guys may be right. If I had multiple chats with different settings fields, (like one didn't have the eightball section) is there an easy way to work with that using a traditional concrete struct.

Comment: @PLZHELP,  https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding. Don't go overboard with embedding though. Often it is simpler to just have two slightly different types. Don't try to mimic inheritance with embedding.

Comment: @PLZHELP here is an example https://goplay.space/#Pn_VaYLM_hO
As I said before and Peter has said, you're gonna want to rip the inner structs out and keep them neat and small. Then you can use nil checking to check if something exist or not.

Answer (score -1):

Super simple fix, just wanted to get some input before I did it. Changed the `map[string]Chat` > `map[string]*Chat` and made a new `*Chat`, then copied the data.

```
data[event.Chat] = &Chat{}
*data[event.Chat] = *data["default"]
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as your first try.

Comment: I changed the type of the map from `map[string]Chat` to `map[string]*Chat` and it worked. *shrug*